# How to handle Foriegnkey in the ModelForm and `Generic createiVew` in Django

Tags: python, django

I have always used normal Django views for years, it is my first time trying to use `Django Generic Views` and is facing this weird problem, 
For some reason, all fields work great, but the `ForiegnKey` field is not even showing, here is my code :

**models.py**

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    #  Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Point_of_sale_Category_detail", args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("Point_of_sale_Category_update", args=(self.pk,))


class Product(models.Model):
    #  Relationships
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_category')

    #  Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Point_of_sale_Product_detail", args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("Point_of_sale_Product_update", args=(self.pk,))
```

And my **forms.py** :

```py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = [
            "name",
            "sell_price",
            "category",
        ]
```

my **views.py**

```py
class ProductCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Product
    form_class = forms.ProductForm
```

And finally here is I use it in my HTML :

```html
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Fields are shown normally but not the `Category` Field

***UPDATE***

for more detailed info. the form renders the field label, but not showing the input part,

[image]

as you see in the image, name and sell price are showing an input field, but not the category , despite the label is there.

Comment: replace `category` with `product_category`

Comment: Gives me `unknown field` error

Comment: Are there records in your `Categories` table?

Comment: @warpri81 yes there is

Comment: Are you using a CSS framework? If you inspect the HTML, is there a `<select>` field that is not being rendered? You may need additional styling or other attributes on the dropdown to have it render correctly. Libraries like [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs) offer template packs for different CSS frameworks.